# How much bandwidth does a Tor Hidden Service have?

Tags: onion-services, relays, client, bandwidth

When I set up a hidden service with Tor, will all clients connect over the same connection between the hidden service and the first relay/router?
What is the bandwidth that I can probably expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you offer a hidden service, your Tor proxy builds a circuit to the rendezvous point. The client which are connecting to your service also build a circuit to the rendezvous point. The rendezvous connects both ends of the circuit (see the [hidden service protcol](https://www.torproject.org/docs/hidden-services.html.en)). You as well as the other side will probably have different relays which they are using.

I'm not aware of bandwidth estimations. However if you offering a popular hidden it may consume a large portion of bandwidth. Silk Road was one of the popular places. The site [Silk Road: Theory & Practice](http://www.gwern.net/Silk%20Road) has some further reading. They link to a paper [»Traveling the Silk Road: A measurement analysis of a large anonymous online marketplace«](https://www.andrew.cmu.edu/user/nicolasc/publications/Christin-WWW13.pdf). Maybe you can find some traffic estimations there.